Power BI Bullet Type Visual
I am creating a Power BI visual similar to the one below with the sum of Actuals, Budget, and Forecast for each Site with a chart next to each.
Visual
Next to each, the chart would indicate the relative position of the actual values against the budget. If the actual sum is below the budget sum, the chart shows green; if it exceeds the budget, it shows orange. There should also be a line (black dots) indicating each site's budget target. The chart should be scaled (if possible).The maximum length of the chart would be the highest value between the budget and the forecast.
Below is a dataset that can be used for testing:
Table Dataset
Is there a visual that can  achieve this or is there an alternative way to achieve a similar visual? How do I go about it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I tried using a bullet chart, a bar chart, a custom bullet chart and a matrix, Each of them either doesn't produce a tablelike structure with the chart (bullet charts and bar charts) or doesn't have a column for such a chart to be displayed.

Use a standard table visual and SVGs. You should be able to adapt something from here: https://kerrykolosko.com/portfolio-category/svg-templates/
